# jQuery show/hide not working

Tags: jquery

This is really strange, and I've been beating my head against it for hours now and can't figure it out.

I'm using jQuery to hide some elements on a form (tagged with the class `.read-only`) and show other elements (tagged with the class `.edit-version`).

Basically, the user clicks an edit link, and within the parent of that link, the read-only items are hidden and the edit items (inputs) are displayed. This works fine.

The problem happens in the response from the server, which is passing back the opposite case. It finds the div that's hosting the form, and it hides the edit versions and displays the read only. Except it doesn't. Here's the code:

```
host = $('#employee-card-49');
$('.edit-version', host).hide();
$('.read-only', host).show();
```

I've verified that it's got the correct div (`#employee-card-49`) is found, and is the right item, and is the only item with that id on the page.

I've verified that `$('.edit-version', host).length` is correct. It returns 3, indicating it's finding the three elements.

I've verified that each returned item from `$('.edit-version', host)` is correct. I can get the properties of them.

No javascript errors come up, but the hide() and show() calls just don't modify the display property at all. I've even tried calling `css('display', 'none')` without avail.

If I change the call to $('.edit-version').hide() call, it works, but that would affect other divs on the page that I don't want to affect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a demo of the code (on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) possibly)?

Comment: @Scott, that's my typo here; there is a ; in the code. I've corrected it. @Rocket: a demo would be hard to do right now. It's not publicly available yet, and it's pretty big to put into a fiddle.

Comment: @Scott not having a `;` wont cause any errors

Comment: Is the server response via AJAX? If it is AJAX, does the response contain HTML, data or a script? Are you sure you are performing the hide/show in a callback or did you forget that the response is asynchronous?

Comment: The response is via AJAX. It returns the script above. If I put an alert in there, it runs and displays the alert without a problem. Also, I should mention that if I remove `host` from the `$('.edit-version')` call, it works. However, it would affect other divs that I don't want it to affect.

Comment: @Neal - I wasn't saying that it would ... just informing him of the typo, which I was sure it was =D

Comment: @Tim Sullivan can you post the related HTML? and is it only certain browsers not working, or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great solution, but it did work. Getting rid of `host` scope altogether and instead using the scope in the selector itself solved the problem.

```
$('#employee-card-49 .edit-version').hide();
$('#employee-card-49 .read-only').show();
```

Weird.

Comment: Which browser does the problem occur in? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Safari 5.0.5, using jQuery 1.6, though the problem happened when I was using jQuery 1.4.4, iirc.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered situations where `show()` and `hide()` don't work due to relative positioning. I'd check to make sure you don't have any weird positioning set, or at least that the position of child elements matches the parents. Also, have you double checked that the `display` attribute isn't getting set by anything else? maybe something's setting it to block or inline with `!important!

Comment: There's no weird positioning going on within the `#employee-card-49` div, but that's contained within a floating div that's acting like a popup. There are no !important css modifiers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the situation where relative position was affecting the hiding and showing? I'm having an issue where an element is not hiding and I think that the relative position may be the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this just solved my problem. I had an !important tag preventing hide from working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
host = '#employee-card-49';
$('.edit-version', host).hide()
$('.read-only', host).show();
```

Comment: That didn't help. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it with `!important` to make sure nothing else is overriding it. Also try setting another CSS property, that's unlikely to be set just to see if it does act on the objects at all.

```
host = $('#employee-card-49');
$('.read-only', host).css({ display: 'block !important',
                            visibility: 'visible !important',
                            // Set unlikely property and see if anything changes
                            letter-spacing: '10px !important' });
```

Also check in Firebug:

- To see the CSS and any inheritance values it may have.
- The computed width, height, padding, etc of the object (layout & computed tab)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was getting different show/hide behavior between Chrome and Safari. Turns out Safari needed the element AND the ID, not just the ID. So:

```
$('form#myform').hide(); //Correct
```

NOT

```
$('#myform').hide(); //Problematic
```

Probably better to be verbose anyway.